# How to check grace period using laravel cashier and stripe?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

Im using Laravel 5.2 and Laravel cashier. It seems to be working and able to subscribe users to plans, cancel plans and resume plans. But when I try to do a grace period check I get an error that reads:

`Call to a member function onGracePeriod() on null`

My code is:

```
if ($user->subscription('Pro')->onGracePeriod()) {
  $userOnGrace = "true";
}

echo $userOnGrace;
```

I followed the instructions on https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/billing#checking-subscription-status

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means your `$user->subscription('Pro')` return null( this user doesn't subscribed to "Pro"). You can check try to like that:

```
if ($user->subscription('Pro') && $user->subscription('Pro')->onGracePeriod()) {
  $userOnGrace = "true";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Really helped.